# When do you need node inside a stage in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is the difference between the following two? When do you have to use the `node` part and when not?

```
stage ("stage") {
    node ("NodeName"){
        xxx
    }
}
```

vs

```
stage ("stage") {
  xxx
}
```

I'm defining `agent any` in the beginning of my pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node` allocates an executor to run steps on. If a step implementation requires a `FilePath` as part of it's execution context,it will fail if it is not in a node body. Some step implementations require that context, some don't:

A few examples of steps requiring a `FilePath` would be:

- [`sh`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)
- [`fileExists`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace)
- [`stash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)
- [`archive`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#archive-archive-artifacts)

A few that don't:

- [`retry`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times)
- [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job)
- [`node`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#node-allocate-node)
- [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input)

Some plugin steps will not be clear if they require an executor or not, so it can just be easiest to try it out.

Comment: Will a jenkins pipeline run al its stages on the same slave? I put some script in the workspace using my pipeline and sometimes I can run the script and sometimes not? (Will it always work when I put my stages inside node steps?

Comment: Or is it because I run a sh step with a path (without node) and than it failed sometimes. If I put 'node' around it it seems to work

Comment: Maybe it's better to put my stages in a node instead of a node in every stage?

Comment: It depends if you are using scripted or declarative pipelines, as they work differently.

Comment: Yes I do use declerative, that was not clear in the question, while your answer is right for scripted. thanks

Comment: In declarative, there isn't as much of the concept of "steps" since it is a specialized DSL. There is the [`agent`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) section that does something under the hood to construct the pipeline so that the `FilePath` context is available to executing steps. I didn't say that every `sh` step always requires a surrounding `node`, because that isn't necessarily true. The `sh` step requires that the context in which it is executed in has the `FilePath` available to it, which could be scripted or declarative or anything else. I hope that is helpful.